# Rspec and capybara, difference between visit and get methods, with regards to the current_path object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm possibly confusing rack and capybara methods here

```
let!(:admin){FactoryGirl.create(:admin)}

# test passes
describe "visiting #edit page" do
  before { visit edit_user_path(admin) }
  specify { current_path.should eq(edit_user_path(admin)) }
end

# test fails
describe "getting #edit page" do
  before { get edit_user_path(admin) }
  specify { current_path.should eq(edit_user_path(admin)) }
end
```

The second test fails with:

```
     Failure/Error: specify { current_path.should eq(edit_user_path(admin)) }

       expected: "/users/51/edit"
            got: "/users/51"

       (compared using ==)
```

A `before(:each)` block, sets the current_path to `/users/51`, so it looks like it remains that way when using `get`.

I just want to check here:

- do **visit** and **current_path** come from capybara, whereas **get** comes from rack?
- does the **current_path** object necessarily require you to use the **visit** method, in order to keep it updated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is a shared issue and was [described in a post by Jose Valim](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/06/improving-the-integration-between-capybara-and-rspec/).

To be short, in integration tests, only use `visit`.