# Capybara can't find link on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec2

I'm trying to get my first capybara tests going.  I following Ryan Bate's philosophy and putting some functional tests into my controller spec files.

```
describe UsersController do
  render_views

  it "can get the home page" do
    get 'home'
    response.body.should include("Login")
  end

  it "should log in" do
    get 'home'
    puts response.body
    click_link('Login')
    response.body.should include("Email")
    response.body.should include("Password")
  end

end
```

In it should login I ran into problems so began with just trying to make sure I can find and click the link. No luck.  In the test as above I'm just trying to make sure the link exists

The `puts response.body` produces the following output

```
...
  <div id="user_nav">
      <a href="/users/sign_up">Register</a> or <a href="/users/sign_in" id="Login">Login</a>
  </div>
...
```

and I also see the element on the actual page.  It seems only my test can't find it. The first test does pass.

```
 1) UsersController should log in
     Failure/Error: click_link('Login')
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       no link with title, id or text 'Login' found
     # (eval):2:in `click_link'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm using Rails 3.2, Rpsec 2.11 and Capybara 1.1.2.

(I've already checked the other questions on stackoverflow as well as a few tutorials and screencasts.  I can't see any reason it can't find an element given an id tag, but I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Why does your error mention `click_link('Terms')` when your spec is calling `click_link('Login')`?

Comment: As I was posting, I thought maybe there was something special about that link (although the code doesn't suggest anything) so I then tried it with a link in my footer.  I must have pasted the error after I switched the code.  I'll fix it above, but the error seems to happen with multiple links on the page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the reason it's not working is that you're using `get` for what is essentially an integration test. See this post: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/06/improving-the-integration-between-capybara-and-rspec/

If my understanding is correct, you need to use `visit` in order to use `click_link` on the page:

```
it "should log in" do
  visit home_path
  click_link('Login')
  page.should ...
end
```

See also this answer on SO: [Rspec and capybara, difference between visit and get methods, with regards to the current_path object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090038/rspec-and-capybara-difference-between-visit-and-get-methods-with-regards-to-th)

Comment: Thanks Shioyama for both the solution and the link.  Very much appreciated.