# Capybara can't click link, response contains shows the link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to write a test that clicks a link but when I run the test, Capybara returns the following error:

```
 "no link with title, id or text 'New Mwod post' found
```

so I put a 'debugger' and printed the response. The body contained the following:

```
<a href=\"/mwod_posts/new\">New Mwod post</a>
```

the test has the following code:

```
describe "GET /mwod_posts/new" do
  it "creates a new mwod post" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:mwod_tag)
    get mwod_posts_path
    debugger
    response.status.should be(200)
    click_link "New Mwod post"
  end
end
```

Any ideas why capybara can't click the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `get` when you should be using [`visit`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/c/capybara-1.1.2/Capybara/Session.html#method-i-visit).

Switch:

```
get mwod_posts_path
```

to:

```
visit mwod_posts_path
```

That will let you click links with `click_link` etc. To parse the response, you'll need to change:

```
response.status.should be(200)
```

to:

```
page.response_code.should be(200)
```

I haven't actually confirmed that this works, but [discussion elsewhere](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ruby-capybara/KdMvhjcjm8E) would seem to indicate you can check response codes this way from `page`. Although, as noted in that discussion, this is not something you should really be doing in integration tests.

For more see on the difference between `get` and `visit` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090038/rspec-and-capybara-difference-between-visit-and-get-methods-with-regards-to-th) and [this post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/06/improving-the-integration-between-capybara-and-rspec/). (This is a common point of confusion.).

Comment: Thanks, I read some more. get PATH and response.status work in normal integration tests. Capybara uses visit and page.response_code. Response.status is not populated via capybara, so that won't work. Thanks again.