# Check page response on multiple pages with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I'm using Capybara with Ruby on Rails to create an integration test that will fill in all of the fields and submit the form. This will then load a new page to the browser. Is it possible to get the response for this second page in the test?

```
describe "the signup process", :type => :request do
    it "signs me in" do
      visit sign_up_path
      fill_in 'user_first_name', :with => "Jhonny"
      t1 = Time.new
      fill_in 'user_email', :with => "joe412@offerslot.com"
      fill_in 'user_last_name', :with => "Bravo"
      fill_in 'user_zip_code', :with => "94102"
      fill_in 'user_password', :with => "password1234"

      click_button 'user-button'
      response.should be_success 
      response.body should_contain("Text on next page")
    end
end
```

Comment: `visit` does not return a response, you have to use `get` for that. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090038/rspec-and-capybara-difference-between-visit-and-get-methods-with-regards-to-th In this case though, since you're browsing more than one page, `get` won't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use capybara's `visit` you cannot access the response status, because capybara does not provide that info. If you want to analyze the response status you have to use the normal HTTP request verbs (i.e. `get`, `post` etc), but those won't work for the case you describe since your test involves multiple pages.

(The use of `visit` versus `get` is a common point of confusion. See [this post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/06/improving-the-integration-between-capybara-and-rspec/) by José Valim for details.)

So basically, the answer is: don't test the response status in your integration tests.

But you shouldn't really be doing this anyway. Integration tests are meant to test what the user actually sees, i.e. what comes up in the browser. You don't "see" a response status, what you see is the actual page and whatever is in it, so that's really what you should be testing. In your test above, that's what you're doing with the line `response.body should_contain("Text on next page")`. That's enough to ensure that the response was successful.

If you want to test aspects of your application which are exclusively API-like, then I'd recommend using rspec request specs for that (which are essentially integration tests but focused on one-step request/response.) You can use `get` requests and analyze the response using capybara matchers.