# Why I can't find h1 tag?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

Here is my test:

```
require "rspec"

describe HomeController do
  render_views

  it "should renders the home" do
    get :home
    response.should render_template("home")
    find('H1').should have_content("Simulate Circuits Online")

  end

end
```

But I get:

```
1) HomeController should renders the home
     Failure/Error: find('H1').should have_content("Simulate Circuits Online")
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "H1"
     # ./spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # (eval):6:in `block in fork'
```

How to find a tag, or ID, or a CSS ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use capybara matchers on the response you get from request methods like `get`, `post`, etc. For capybara matchers, you have to use `visit`, as in `visit 'home'`.

See [this post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/06/improving-the-integration-between-capybara-and-rspec/) for details. This quote in particular:

> Capybara, being an acceptance test framework, does not expose low-level details like a request or response object. In order to access a web page using Capybara, the developer needs to use the method visit (instead of get). To read the accessed page body, the developer must use page instead of manipulating the response.

See also this post: [Check page response on multiple pages with Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648839/check-page-response-on-multiple-pages-with-capybara)

If you want to test the structure of an HTML string response, you might consider [rspec-html-matchers](https://github.com/kucaahbe/rspec-html-matchers).

Comment: But how to visit an action without hardcoding it?

Comment: You can use e.g. `visit home_path`, assuming `home_path` is defined in your routes.